# nftables: How to match ethernet locally administered address in saddr?

Tags: netfilter

How can I match packets in `nft` *rules* with it's [`ether saddr`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Ether) set to an [locally administered address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Universal_vs._local)?

I thought about using the same notation as shown for `meta` and `ct mark` [syntax](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Ct), E.g.:

`ether saddr and 0x02 == 0x02`

Can i use `set`, `and`, `or` and `xor` here too?
But how would I address the 7th-most-significant-bit to be set?

**Bonus:** how would I limit my match for Unicast only?